# A question on Stable rank 1

Tags: c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

My apology in advance if my question is elementary

According to the initial definition of topological stable rank introduced by Marc Rieffel we have  the following:

An algebra has  tsr  1 if the space of  left invertible element is dense equivalently the space of  right invertible elements is dense but why this is equivalent the space of  invertible elements is a dense subset?

Comment: Left invertibles dense actually implies that every left invertible is invertible.

Comment: Reference: B. Nica, [Homotopical stable ranks for Banach algebras](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123611000929) (J. Funct. Anal. **261**, 2011), Proposition 3.5

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  That is  a very excellent reference, thank you very much for that!

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  I can not find your home page and  your email address. I would appreciate if you send me an email to my yahoo email "alitghv@yahoo.com". Thank you